# Populate Option Value

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to populate an option value.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 300; $i++) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">1.<?php  print $i; ?> AVAX</option>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

I want for the above code to work something like this. `1.00 - 1.99` after reaching `1.99` I want it to navigate to `2.00 - 2.99` and so forth and onward until the numbers run out. How can I achieve that? The above result returns only `1.300`

Comment: so what's the number will be? `1.00,1.01,1.02 .......... till 300.00`?

Comment: This is a simple conversion: `1+($i-1)/100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the increment to whatever you want

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 300; $i+=0.01) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo number_format($i, 2, '.', ''); ?>"><?php  echo number_format($i, 2, '.', ''); ?> AVAX</option>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/GMk6WJ)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `until numbers run out?`
You do realize that numbers are infinite.
Therefore, I can only assume that you want the options to have the series:
1.01, 1.02.... 1.99, 2.00, 2.01, 2.02, .... until 10.00.

If 10 is not the highest number you want to reach, then you can change the end limit of $i in the following code:

```php
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
   for ($j = 0; $j <= 99; $j++) { 

         $num = "$i." . sprintf('%02d',$j);   // 1.01, 1.02, ...

         echo '<option value="' . $num . '">AVAX</option>';
        
   }
}
?>
```